# SBT SCALA java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Authenticator

Tags: java, scala, apache, email, sbt

I have SBT Scala project who sends emails with some information to users. Everything works fine using IntelliJ to run it, but I need to build the project, put on the server and run from terminal.

In the first step I use below command to build the project:

> sbt clean compile package

after that I try to run it by:

> scala target/scala-2.12/project_name_sbt_2.12-0.1.jar

then I got error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Authenticator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

It is command line app, I don't use Tomcat and other containers. Construction is simple and easy. I have a main class like:

```
object MyApp extends App {new SomeService().run()}
```

I have build.sbt like:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
          "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % "test",
          "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.16",
          "org.jsoup" % "jsoup" % "1.11.2",
          "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.10.1",
          "org.apache.commons" % "commons-email" % "1.5"
        )
```

Could you point me to the right direction to resolve that issue? What's wrong?

Comment: Before fiddling around with dependencies, can you try to [create a FAT jar](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) and see if that works?

Comment: Long story short, when you `package`, SBT will compile your classes to **Java Bytecode** and then will create a **JAR** with those - that means for running your app you need **Scala** to be installed on the server as well as your libraries _(and present in the `CLASSPATH`)_. However, when you `assembly` _(using the already pointed plugin)_, SBT will compile your classes and included them as well as all of its dependencies _(including the Scala standard library)_ together in one JAR - thus, you only need the JRE to run your app as `java -jar app.jar`.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use this [plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) to create the jar. 
Try to add it to your plugins.sbt file

and run this command to create the jar:

```
sbt "set test in assembly := {}" assembly
```

and then try to run your jar again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Markus Appel, Luis Miguel Mejia Suarez, and Mahmoud Hanafy. As you recommended I used assembly and it works fine for me.